# After refreshing checkbox should get unchecked

Tags: bootstrap-4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8u0eg.png)First click(check) the  checkbox,and after i refresh the table, it should get unchecked.
But remains there...

[image]

Comment: can you please provide more details? I really don't understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Let me know if my answer is what you wanted

Comment: if you can provide some code snipet or something

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JQuery then you can do this way.

```
$('button').click(function(){       //Put the id of the Refresh Button

  $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked',false);

})
```